# Django ModelViewSet PATCH request return model fields updated

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class MerchantStampCardViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    A view set for listing/retrieving/updating/deleting stamp cards for the current
    merchant
    '''
        permission_classes = (IsMerchantAndAuthenticated, )

def get_queryset(self):
    if len(MerchantProfile.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)) > 0:
        merchant_profile = MerchantProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if merchant_profile.merchant:
            return StampCard.objects.filter(merchant=merchant_profile.merchant)
    return None

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        return StampCardSerializerWithRewards
    else:
        return StampCardSerializer
```

I'm trying to make this code return the fields changed in the response body. The model class has a couple fields like name, city, province, zip code and address and through the front-end the user can only change one at a time, but I want the body of the 200 response to contain the field name changed and the new value just to confirm that a change was successful and nothing went wrong.

So for example if the user changes the name to Billy. The response should be 200 and the body should say {name : 'Billy'}

How do I do this?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to return only the updated fields and not all the fields of that object ?

Comment: yes! Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
class YourViewSet(...):

  def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    current_data = self.get_serializer(instance).data  # collect current data
    # next few lines of the code is from default implementation
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    updated_data = serializer.data  # now we get the updated data
    response_dict = dict()
    for key, value in current_data:
         # find the differences
         if updated_data.get(key) != value:
            response_dict[key] = updated_data.get(key)
    return Response(response_dict)  # send the difference through response
```

Here I have put a override on update method. Then I have collected the dictionary data from current object and updated object. Then compared them and sent differences in a dictionary as response. *FYI* its an untested code.